# Unable to crawl some HTML Elements only exist in F12 menu

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I'm pretty new to python and is trying to crawl a site that is refreshing itself very frequently(which causes the element I'm trying to crawl having an unstable pointer) and targetted elements do not exist in source code.
[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UrIV.png),[HTML marked out are targetted elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPNuC.png).
In case you need the link, its: http://www.beijingrtj.com/

When I try using:

```
html = r.get(url).text
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('b').text
```

It only returned an AttributeError to me:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Then I try using list() on data, it returned an empty list to me. What else other than request and BeautifulSoup can I use?

Comment: `find_all` returns a `ResultSet`,  ResultSets do not have a `text` attribute. Get rid of `text` and print `data`. You'll understand the problem.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded via Javascript from external URL. You can use `requests` module to simulate this call:

```py
import requests

url = "http://www.beijingrtj.com/admin/get_price5.php?=&t=1697284159486"

response = requests.post(url)
_, *data, time = response.text.split(",")

i = iter(data[:10])
for (col1, col2), col3 in zip(zip(i, i), data[10:]):
    print(f"{col1:<10} {col2:<10} {col3:<10} {time:<10}")
```

Prints:

```
460.80     461.80     459.65     19:56:15  
5.500      5.630      344.22     19:56:15  
210.7      212.8      198.8      19:56:15  
277.0      280.0      267.3      19:56:15  
0.0        0.0        4.400      19:56:15
```